# Is sequence $(f(a_n))$ convergent for every Cauchy $(a_n)$ in X, if $f$ is continuous?

Tags: continuity, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

"If $f$ is a continuous function in metric X; $f: X →R$, and  prove or give a counter example with proof, for  every Cauchy $a_n$ in X, the sequence of $(f(a_n))$ is convergent in R."

I need hand in this question. I proved this for the case of uniform continuous. But I could not solve this part. My attempt was giving counter example with $f(x)= 1/x$. But I could not construct it with Cauchy sequence. Could you help me on that?

Comment: No offense, but I would be very surprised if anybody would be willing to answer such a poorly formatted question... If you would like others to make an effort to help you, could you please make an effort yourself first? At least, spell out all the important words. And then make the post generally readable too. If you don't have time to spell "continuous", do you expect us to have time to help you?

Comment: I am sorry about that. I am fixing them. But the writing the formulas or math terms, I do not how to use. Therefore I wrote all in words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be the open interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, with the metric inherited from the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=\tan(x)$.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of elements of $X$ which converges in $\mathbb{R}$ to $\pi/2$.

Then $f$ is continuous, and the sequence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, but the sequence $f(x_n)$ is unbounded, so doesn't converge in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thank you so much .